# Jquery, javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I'll try to explain this to the best of my ability. What I want to do is that, I want to use the slider (image i posted) as a navigation. Like when you move the knob of the slider to the next circle thing, a different page comes up. I have looked everywhere. Tried everything, and I just can't seem to achieve this effect. Can someone please help me?

http://static.tumblr.com/1f1tzta/5Fgm5zft9/slider.png

Comment: What do you have so far? What specific issue are you having trouble with?

Comment: I scraped all my coding so as of right now I don't have anything. I even tried to achieve the desired effect with css but it wouldn't work. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

It's a jQuery UI slider which you can fully style and script.

Comment: I saw this and it's not what I want

Comment: @user1377298, can you be a bit more specific? You could use [snap to increments](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps) and then redirect the user on the `slidechange` event. From what I understand, that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

- [jQuery Slider plugin on GitHub](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/)
- [85 Awesome jQuery Slider Plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/03/jquery-slider.html)
- [13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)
- [37 Fresh jQuery Image, Content Sliders And Slideshows](http://www.smashingapps.com/2012/05/22/37-fresh-jquery-image-content-sliders-and-slideshows.html)

Comment: No none of those are what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I know two sliders that can meet your requirements.

1. [Menucool jQuery Slider](http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider):

   This jQuery Slider has two event handlers that you can use to switch to your corresponding pages before or after the slide:

   ```
   function beforeThumbChange(args) {
       //args[0]: next slide index
       //you can switch to your page here: $("#pageToDisplay").load("/mypage"+args[0]+".html");
   }
   function afterThumbChange(args) {
       //args[0]: currentSlide index
       //you can also switch to your page here: $("#pageToDisplay").load("/mypage"+args[0]+".html");
   }
   ```

2.

http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

```
    function beforeSlideChange(args) {
        //args: [0]-next slide index, [1]-next image, [2]-next caption, [3]-next effect
        //$("#pageToDisplay").load("/mypage"+args[0]+".html");
    }

    /*
    function afterSlideChange(args) {
        //args: [0]-currentSlide index, [1]-currentImage
        //$("#pageToDisplay").load("/mypage"+args[0]+".html");
    }
```

You just need to add one of the handler functions in your page (at the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>`), and implement your page displaying code there. The slider will trigger the handler by each slide.